# Excel VBA: Set Discontinious Range (Multiple Rows/Columns) Equal to Continuous Range (Multiple Rows/Columns) in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, set, range

Goal: Write VBA sub that will set a discontinuous range, specifically 13 columns - every other column - equal to a continuous range of data 13 columns wide and 132 rows long upon a click event.

I have two financial statements I want to be able to compare side-by-side. Click the active x button, insert columns in between the columns of financial statement 1 then take the columns from financial statement 2 (contained in another sheet) and have them appear next to the corresponding column in financial statement 1.

Using only VBA code. Take what is

Totals|January|February|March.... and make it

Totals|Totals|January|January|Feburary|Feburary|March|March.....

The current code I've developed runs extremely slow and for some reason inserts a "June" column in between each column.

Help!

```
Sub BudgetBudgetCheck_Click()

If BudgetActual.Value = "True" And BudgetBudgetCheck.Value = "True" Then
    For colx = 6 To 36 Step 2
    Columns(colx).Insert shift = xlRight
    Next
    End Sub

Private Sub BudgetActual_Click()
For i = 4 To 28 Step 2
For j = 2 To 14
Columns(i).Value = Worksheets("P&L - Monthly Budget").Columns(j).Value
Next
Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: can u show a screen shot of both the files and also a screenshot of how the final file should look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rngOne as range, rngTwo as range, x as long, col_offset

Set rngOne = worksheets("statement1").Range("A1").resize(132,13)
Set rngTwo = worksheets("statement2").Range("A1").resize(132,13)

with worksheets("summary")
    .usedrange.clearcontents
    for x=1 to 13
        col_offset = (x-1)*2      
        rngOne.columns(x).copy .cells(1,col_offset+1)
        rngTwo.columns(x).copy .cells(1,col_offset+2)
    next x
end with
```